# Signed Global IDs for Authentication Tokens - secure or vulnerable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, devise, token

I found that *Signed Global IDs* are awesome for token based stuff like **reset password** and **account confirmation** functions and would love to get opinions about its security and usability.

Common ways besides using the Devise gem (module Confirmable + Recoverable) is

A) generate tokens (e.g. `d3f64ce7c125410498b5393b33e7cf3c`), save them in the DB and send links to `/account_confirmation/#token#`

B) saving digests of these tokens in the DB and only sending the tokens in mails - than compare them with `BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)`. This more secure approach is what [Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation) is using in his Rails Tutorial.

---

**C. But what about Signed Global IDs?!**

Since Rails 4.2 the [Global ID Gem](https://github.com/rails/globalid) is included in Rails, manly used for ActiveJobs. That is how I now use them for e.g. account confirmation stuff:

Include `GlobalID::Identification` in your User Model, than:

```
>> user_sgid = User.last.to_sgid(expires_in: 2.hours, for: 'confirmation')
=> #<SignedGlobalID:0x008fde45df8937

>> sgid_token = user_sgid.to_s
=> "BAhJIh5naWQ6Ly9pZGluYWlkaS9Vc2VyLzM5NTk5BjoGRVQ=--81d73[...]20e"
```

This token you can send via email with a account confirmation link to your users, `/account_confirmation/##sgid_token##`.

There is no need saving `account_confirmation_token` or a digest of it in the DB. Also you do not need to save `account_confirmation_sent_at` Timestamp to check if the link is still valid - all is included in the sgid_token:

```
>> GlobalID::Locator.locate_signed(sgid_token, for: 'confirmation')
=> #<User:0x007fae94bf6298 @id="1">
# use the User model to activate the account, login, and so on

# 2 hours later if link expired:
>> GlobalID::Locator.locate_signed(sgid_token, for: 'confirmation')
=> nil
```

You can send multiple links with different tokens, different expiration times and use cases. I love this approach.

More information in the gem description on github.

---

**My questions:**

- is the Signed Global ID token secure or vulnerable against specific attacks?
- any disadvantage of not saving tokens/digest + sent_at into DB?
- sgid_tokens get up to around 200+ chars, so links get quite long, any problems about this?
- other reasons why not using Signed Global ID but therefore tokens/digests?

Answer (score 4):

> is the Signed Global ID token secure or vulnerable against specific attacks?

The Signed Global ID appears to use [`MessageVerifier`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html):

> MessageVerifier creates HMAC signatures using SHA1 hash algorithm

[HMAC over SHA1 is still considered secure](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html).

> any disadvantage of not saving tokens/digest + sent_at into DB?

The main disadvantage in general is there is no way for you to revoke these server-side. For example, if a user logs out or if you wish to expire all sessions for a particular user.

Also make sure there is some context saved within each Global ID. That is, a user with a forgotten password Signed ID should not be able to use it for an authentication token.

> sgid_tokens get up to around 200+ chars, so links get quite long, any
>   problems about this?

Not in particular, no.

> other reasons why not using Signed Global ID but therefore
>   tokens/digests?

Mainly the fact you can't see them or revoke them server-side as mentioned above. You should also ensure you are using a strong key (>= 128 bits) and this key remains private. Any leakage of the key compromises all tokens and allows an attacker to generate their own.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your opinions on this! And yeah you are absolutely right about using context with each GlobalID with the "for: '...'" option, e.g. I differ between `account_confirmation` and `reset_password`. When storing digest in the DB (not the token) it is also not possible to "see" the token - but your point about revoking is a good point ... I therefore use the `expire_in` to ensure links a are not valid to long - but complete revoking would not be possible.